# Validar URL Expressão regular

Tags: delphi, regex, delphi-xe5

Gostaria de saber o seguinte, tenho um expressão regular para validar URLs, mas gostaria que além de validar a URL, ela liberasse caso a URL esteja vazia ou com espaços em branco:

Eu acredito que a ideia era essa, mas quando rodo o Delphi, as URLs vazias e as que possuem espaços em branco não funcionam

```
^[\s]*$|/(((http|ftp|https):\/{2})+(([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mn|mo|mp|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|nom|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ra|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw|arpa)(:[0-9]+)?((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b/imuS
```

Testando pela internet funciona, mas quando usado no Delphi, ele não valida os espaços em branco e nem se a string estiver vazia, apenas a URL ele valida.

Será que é problema esta no Delphi?

Comment: Aonde entra o `PHP`, e `Javascript`? Lembre-se que cada linguagem tem suas peculiaridades em relação a `expressões regulares`, se uma expressão funciona em PHP, não quer dizer que vá funcionar em Ruby, etc.

Comment: Então @Gerep, é que testei em sites online que devem utilizar JS ou PHP. Agora você falando que cada linguagem tem suas peculiaridades, deve ser este um dos motivos de não funcionar a validação do vazio '^[\s]*$|' . Pois nos testes online, elas funciona, quando testava no delphi, não funcionavam. ATT

Answer (score 1):

**Considerações**:
Não vejo necessidade de uma regex tão extensa, no caso definiria uma URL com algo que comece com o prefixo http OU https OU ftp, seguida de "://www." endereço e final ".com", ".br", ".gov", etc.

Para os casos que contém espaços em branco ou vazio, utilizaria um token de alternativa OU após a expressão de URL, então caso não fosse o padrão que você deseja, ele verificaria se é HTTP OU FTP OU um campo vazio (note que estou usando a sequencia de caracteres mais específicas antes e depois as mais comuns, isso não é por acaso [veja aqui o porque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231998/ordem-de-avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o-das-alternativas-em-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular-%C3%A9-sempre-levada-em/232018?noredirect=1#comment475015_232018))

**Sendo assim eu utilizaria essa expressão:**

```
( *?https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}.*| *?ftp:\/\/w{0,3}.*| *?\n|^$)
```

[Você pode testa-la aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/v96Dku/3)