# Ordem de avaliação das alternativas em uma expressão regular é sempre levada em consideração?

Tags: regex

Estava aqui desenvolvendo uma função que pegava uma sequência lógica de caracteres, vamos chamar de "query", essa query representa expressões simples separadas por `;`, as expressões podem conter qualquer uma dessas operações: `==`, `!+`, `>`, `<`, `<=`, `=>`,`~=`  que representam uma validação entre atributo e valor, eu preciso pegar essa string e separar ela em um array de objetos com cada uma dessas propriedades separadas.

Por exemplo:

> "temperature==40;engine!=fail;speed>90;speed<90;speed>=90;speed<=90;speed~=90"

viraria:

`[
  {attr: "temperature",op: "==",value:"40"},
  {...}
]`

Eu resolvi esse problema usando .split passando a expressão regular `/(==|!=|>=|<=|~=|>|<)/`, só que eu não tenho certeza se a expressão regular executará em ordem, como eu tenho `>=` e `<=` eu coloquei `>` e `<` no final, para que não fosse capturado sem que fosse analizado todas as alternativas da expressão.

```js
var exprA = /(==|!=|>=|<=|~=|>|<)/;
var exprB = /(==|!=|~=|>|<|>=|<=)/;
var q = "temperature==40;engine!=fail;speed>90;speed<90;speed>=90;speed<=90;speed~=90";
var opts = q.split(';');
console.info('Expr. A');
for (var i in opts) {
  var parts = (opts[i] || "").split(exprA);
  console.log(parts.join(' '));
}

console.info('Expr. B:');
for (var i in opts) {
  var parts = (opts[i] || "").split(exprB);
  console.log(parts.join(' '));
}
```

Veja no exemplo acima, na "expressão B" foi retornado primeiro o resultado para 
 `>` e não `>=`, o que não ocorreu na expressão A, a teoria se confirma mas não tenho certeza.

Existe alguma documentação RFC que confirme que as expressões regulares executam suas opções em ordem em todas as situações, usos e linguagens de programação?

Comment: quando você diz ordem, você quer dizer a ordem de analise da regex? ou se o retorno se dá em ordem de captura?

Comment: Exatamente, se no grupo que eu criei na refez(vide snippet) ele irá retornar o resultado  na ordem que as condições foram escritas na regex, ou se isso depende

Comment: vejo que editou a pergunta, é isso mesmo, todo flavour de regex funciona da mesma maneira (talvez possua diferentes operadores para cada coisa, porém o funcionamento é o mesmo), ele irá analisar primeiramente o que está a esquerda e indo gradativamente verificando se cada OR está satisfeito, até o fim da expressão, na direita.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ficar mais claro a minha dúvida. E mudei as referências no snippet.

Comment: Verifique se era isso que você queria, espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe alguma documentação RFC que confirme que as expressões
>   regulares executam suas opções em ordem em todas as situações, usos e
>   linguagens de programação?

[Sim, você pode encontrar a documentação sobre seu problema aqui:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

> Veja no exemplo acima, na "expressão B" foi retornado primeiro o resultado para  > e não >=, o que não ocorreu na expressão A, a teoria se confirma mas não tenho certeza.

O que você testou com as expressões **A** e **B**, está correto e é
 reproduzido em todos os flavours de Regex, o que mudam neles são os
 seus *tokens, operators e modifiers*.
Então posso confirmar (*afinal você acabou de provar*) que:
**Uma regex com o operador OR** (`|`) **verifica suas possibilidades da esquerda para direita e assim que satisfeita, não verifica mais aquele caractere, segue a analise a partir do próximo**

É por isso que mesmo que você tenha a possibilidade de ser encontrado tanto "<=" e "<" se expressar a busca na regex dessa forma: `(<|<=)`

Em um texto como esse:`1<=1`

Você vai capturar somente **<**, pois a regex vai verificar se a primeira condição foi satisfeita e depois a segunda em cada caractere e SE a condição for completamente satisfeita, nem vai analisar o segunda possibilidade, vai retomar a analise a partir da posição seguinte na cadeia de caracteres.

**Então no caso dessa pequena analise**

- A regex verifica primeiramente o **1**.
  satisfaz a primeira condição? **NÃO** 
  satisfaz a segunda condição? **NÃO**
- Depois o **<** 
  satisfaz a primeira condição? **SIM** / COMPLETAMENTE? **SIM**
  Então captura e segue a analise.
- E assim verifica o **=**  
  satisfaz a primeira condição? **NÃO** 
  satisfaz a segunda condição? **NÃO**, pois o "**<**" que era necessário para essa segunda possibilidade já foi capturado pela primeira.

Comment: Bacana, a resposta está bem clara (+1) confirmou a teoria, obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: sem problema, caso tenha problemas novamente pode me chamar através do chat @LeonanCarvalho